# Orbeon Form Builder database service for populating drop down not working

Tags: orbeon

I am creating a form using Form Builder. I have a section with 1 dynamic drop down element, named `simple-query`.

I created database service as follows:

- Service name: simple-query
- DataSource: prp
- SQL Query:

  ```
  select OpsiName 
  from CPP_ORG_PartnerBusinessRelationshipItem 
  where 
  PartnerLocationId='70734968'
  ```

And an action as follows:

- Action name:simple-query-action
- Condition:Run always
- Run Action when: the form loads - after the controls are ready
- Service to Call:simple-query
- Service Response Action
- Set Control Choices > Simple Query(simple-query) >
- Return one node for each choice: /response/row
- Relative to choice tem node: OpsiName
- Relative to choice node: OpsiName

I created test.jsp page in my orbeon web application to test the jdbc data source, and it was successful. But my drop down not populated. Anything I missed here?

Comment: In the Actions Editor, could you try changing `OpsiName` to `opsiname`, i.e. all lowercase? If that doesn't help, still leave it in lowercase, and when you open the form, monitor the `orbeon.log`; do you see any error there?

Comment: hi @avernet, seems that if the column name contains underscore ( _ ), the value will not be loaded. My column name was company_name, after I changed to companyname then it worked.

Comment: If it contains an underscore, that character is transformed in a dash. So if in your database you have `company_name`, then in Form Builder you should enter `company-name`. This was made way-back-when, with the idea that using dashes is more XML-like than underscores, but I understand how confusing this can be! And of course, avoiding the underscore, like you did, works as well!

Comment: I also posted an answer below, so people finding this through a search can save themselves the time of going through all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Per Chris' comments, the issue was that the SQL query was doing a `SELECT company_name FROM …`. Because of the underscore in the column name, when referring to that column in Form Builder, you should us a dash, as in `company-name`.